# How to convert percentile rank into z score in R

Tags: r, quantiles, z-statistic

I have a vector of percentile ranks. I want to convert them into z-scores, so it will be interval scale. I have to do it in R, but I could not find a function or package that can do this. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why do you think something that converts percentile ranks into something that's nominally a z-score will leave you with an interval scale?

Comment: @Glen_b is right about this, although in this case the title of your question may be quite accurate; and this is a COVERT action. Can you share, or do you have any information on the raw data as far as distribution?

Comment: Title changed to "convert". I doubt OP was trying for word play here.

Comment: Use the `qnorm` function.

Answer (score 6):

You would apply the inverse cdf to the percentile ranks to convert them to quantiles, so if you want standard normals, $z=\Phi^{-1}(p)$ should do what you seem to be asking for.

However, this transformation won't of itself make an ordinal scale into an interval scale.

In R, you would do this as:

```
z <- qnorm(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c(1 , 1.1 , 1.2) #your z-values in a vector
```

`pnorm(x)` will give the area to the left of the Z-value, which is the percentile. This function can take a vector as an input.

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of what is being asked for: the *input* is supposed to be the percentile ranks and the *output* will be the Z-scores.